# Who is the Morning Star?

Tags: jesus, revelation, isaiah, hebrew-bible, satan

Job 38:7

> When the morning stars sang together, and all the sons of God shouted for joy?

Rev 22:16

> I Jesus have sent mine angel to testify unto you these things in the churches. I am the root and the offspring of David, and the bright and morning star.

Isaiah 14:12

> How art thou fallen from heaven, O Lucifer, son of the morning! how art thou cut down to the ground, which didst weaken the nations!

Important part: The word Satan is mentioned 27 times in the OT and 36 times in the NT.

The word Lucifer is mentioned 1 time in Isaiah 14. If he is Satan in the Old Testament how is he Lucifer in the New Testament?

Lucifer (the morning star) is represented as a winged child pouring light from a jar. Engraving by G. H. Frezza, 1704. In Roman folklore, Lucifer ("light-bringer" in Latin) was the name of the planet Venus, though it was often personified as (a male figure bearing a torch.)
The only male figure I know carrying a torch is the Statue of Liberty.

I don't believe Lucifer and Satan are the same.

God said that Lucifer fell to earth with the fallen angels.

Who was with Adam and Eve in the garden that enticed Eve to eat the apple?

Who is the "morning star" again that sang with another "morning star"?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a statement and not a genuine question.

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for joining the group.  Please remember to take the tour (link below left0 to better understand how this site works.

Comment: The assumption is being made that there is only one morning-star.. If that assumption was made about modern references to "king" or "president", it would be an obvious fallacy.

Answer (score 1):

> Who was with Adam and Eve in the garden that intinced Eve to eat the apple?

The Old Testament does not specify what type of fruit the tree produced.

Genesis 3:2, 3, 6

> 2 And the woman said unto the serpent, We may eat of the **fruit** of the trees of the garden:
> 3 But of the **fruit** of the tree which is in the midst of the garden, God
> hath said, Ye shall not eat of it, neither shall ye touch it, lest ye
> die.
> 6 And when the woman saw that the tree was good for food, and that it was pleasant to the eyes, and a tree to be desired to make one wise, she took of the **fruit** thereof, and did eat, and gave also unto her husband with her; and he did eat.

Answer (score -2):

I believe Satan is the Dragon and the serpent. The Devil existed on Earth before we got here.
But Lucifer is a fallen angel.
So when fallen angels slept with men's women, where are they now?

They were not giants. They were 7 feet tall, and like pleadians they mated with cave women. Which bore what we call common sense. Once you become worry-free, eat plants and fruits lightly then you will be able to use your power.

Comment: Please see the Tour and the Help (below) as to the purpose and the functioning of this, an _hermeneutic_ site where we analyse the _text_ of scripture and do not debate (or arbitrarily assert) opinions. Please also have a look at other answers and see how users conduct themselves. Please also see the archive of 14,254 questions for all the information already stored there.